# How to copy non-contiguous data into the column to the left?

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

Accounting software spits out a report.

How it is currently formatted.
[image]

The account number at the top of each section needs to go into the column A and the account description needs to go into column B.

Normally, I would copy and drag down to copy to all that is needed, but the report has around 40,000 rows.

I tried to think of a formula or function to copy each section without having to do it manually, but was unable to come up with anything, especially with the blank spaces in between each section.

Answer (score 0):

Place the following formulas in columns A&B respectively adjacent to the first account row and copy down as required.

```
Column A
=IF(OR(C4="",C5=""),"",IF(C3="",C4,A4))

Column B
=IF(OR(C4="",C5=""),"",IF(C3="",D4,B4))
```

[image: POC]

Comment: Hey thank you so much for your response! So, one question, since the large amount of rows there are additionally a large amount of account numbers (probably way larger than 100 accounts, I just wanted to give a sample in the screenshot) is there a way to easily grab all of the accounts so that I don't have to enter in each individual account?

Comment: As long as your data is formatted in the way you have shown, you do not need to manually enter any account information.  Just place the formula in the row beside the first account and copy down.  Other than that I am not sure what you mean by manually entering accounts